# How do you find the coefficient of $x^i$ in $(x^0 + x^1 + \cdots + x^n)^k$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Power Series question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/power-series-question)

For example, in the formula $(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + \cdots + x^9)^5$, what is the coefficient of $x^{23}$?

More generally, what is the coefficient of $x^i$ where $0\leq i\leq nk$ ?

I'm really interested in *how* you get an answer. Do you simply count? Do you solve it with generating functions? Even dynamic programming?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/power-series-question/28861#28861).

Comment: Ah, excellent. There is no closed form, as I suspect.